# How to ignore scrolling inside a container when there are many containers inside a ListView?

Tags: flutter

I have a page which contains 4 Containers inside a ListView. When I scrolldown the page it gets stuck inside each Container and I can't scroll properly down. I have to point to the empty places to scroll down.

How can I ignore scrolling inside the Containers and smoothly scroll down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ListView(
     physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics
)
```